# How to implement a shared buffer between Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, shared, producer-consumer

I intended to write a shared buffer between a producer and a consumer thread. Here are my codes:

```
class PQueue
{
    Token token;
    boolean flag = false;   // false: add, true: poll

    PQueue()
    {
        token = null;
    }

    synchronized void add(Token token)
    {
        if(flag == true)
        {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        flag = true;
        notify();
        this.token = token;
    }

    synchronized Token poll()
    {
        if(flag == false)
        {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        flag = false;
        notify();
        return this.token;
    }
}
```

I am new to multithreading. Is there any potential concurrency bugs? Is this a "standard/common" way to achieve this goal? Or is there any much simpler and more efficient way?

Comment: Can't you just use java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue?

Comment: `notify()` inside a synchronized block looks suspicious to me (but can't tell if that works or leads to deadlocks)

Comment: @Andreas_D: you can't call `notify()` any other way, what do you mean suspicious? (His code is suspicious for other reasons, but not that one.)

Comment: @vanza That is a good suggestion. In my case, I only need one-element buffer. Does the BlockingQueue have similar implementation?

Comment: @vanza - a guick tour on google reminded me that you're right. notify has to be called inside a synchronized block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, in particular the [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface and the classes that implement it.  These are meant for passing messages from one thread to another.  The [`SynchronousQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) is exactly what you're trying to implement.

Your own implementation has a few flaws.  For one, both the shared variables should be declared `volatile` to ensure that changes on one thread are seen by the other.  And your `if (flag == false)` and `if (flag == true)` tests should actually be `while` loops, because `wait()` can [wake up spuriously](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) when `notify()` hasn't actually been called.

Rather than having a separate flag variable, I'd suggest just setting the token to null to indicate that there's no object.  And rather than catching, printing, and blindly continuing in the face of `InterruptedException`, I'd recommend letting both methods just throw that exception if it happens.  These are blocking methods, and it's the caller's responsibility to handle the possibility of a blocking method being interrupted.

Also, I don't know what your `Token` class is, but nothing in your queue actually depends on its type.  It'd make more sense to define a generic `PQueue<T>`, and then use `PQueue<Token>` if you want to pass tokens.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Try using the `thread-safe` classes and interfaces from `java.util.concurrent` Package.

**2.** Use the `BlockingQueue` `Interface` along with the `ArrayBlockingQueue` `Class`.